# AVFrame YUV420P to dispmanx VC_IMAGE_YUV420

Tags: video, c++, c, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg for decoding a video with h264_mmal encoder. And all test videos are in YUV420P color encoding. Also I'm using dispmanx for drawing frames from a video. Only problem which I have is that every frame is in green color. I can't use the OpenMAX decoder because I need to know number of decoded frames.

Screenshot:
[image]

My source code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>

#include "bcm_host.h"

static char *IMG = "/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/test.h264";

AVCodecParameters *pVideoCodecParameters = NULL;
AVStream *pAVStream = NULL;
AVPacket avPacket;
AVFormatContext *pFormatContext = NULL;
AVCodecContext *pAVCodecContext = NULL;
AVCodec *pAVCodec = NULL;

int videoStreamIndex = -1;
int videoWidth, videoHeight;

int setupDemuxer(const char *filename){
    if( avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext, filename, NULL, NULL) != 0 ){
        printf("Can't get format\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Retrieve stream information
    if( avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatContext, NULL) ){
        printf("Couldn't find stream information\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //av_dump_format(pFormatContext, 0, filename, 0);

    // Find the first video stream
    videoStreamIndex = -1;
    // Now pFormatCtx->streams is just an array of pointers, of size pFormatCtx->nb_streams, so let's walk through it until we find a video stream
    for(int i = 0; i < pFormatContext->nb_streams; i++){
        if( pFormatContext->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO ){
            videoStreamIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( videoStreamIndex < 0 ){
        return -1;
    }

    pAVStream = pFormatContext->streams[videoStreamIndex];
    pVideoCodecParameters = pAVStream->codecpar;

    videoWidth = pAVStream->codecpar->width;
    videoHeight = pAVStream->codecpar->height;
    //AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder(video_stream->codecpar->codec_id);
    AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("h264_mmal");

    pAVCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(NULL);
    if( avcodec_parameters_to_context(pAVCodecContext, pAVStream->codecpar) < 0 ){
        printf("Could not copy data to context\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Open codec
    if( avcodec_open2(pAVCodecContext, codec, NULL) < 0 ){
        printf("Could not open codec\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint32_t displayNumber = 0;
    VC_IMAGE_TYPE_T type = VC_IMAGE_YUV420;

    bcm_host_init();

    if( argc > 1 ){
        IMG = argv[1];
    }
    setupDemuxer(IMG);


    DISPMANX_DISPLAY_HANDLE_T display = vc_dispmanx_display_open(displayNumber);

    DISPMANX_MODEINFO_T info;
    int result = vc_dispmanx_display_get_info(display, &info);

    uint32_t pVCImage;

    DISPMANX_RESOURCE_HANDLE_T bgResource = vc_dispmanx_resource_create(type, pAVCodecContext->width, pAVCodecContext->height, &pVCImage);
    assert(bgResource != 0);

    VC_RECT_T sourceRectangle;
    VC_RECT_T destinationRectangle;

    vc_dispmanx_rect_set(&destinationRectangle, 0, 0, pAVCodecContext->width, pAVCodecContext->height);
    uint32_t background = 1;

    vc_dispmanx_resource_write_data(bgResource, type, sizeof(background), &background, &destinationRectangle);

    DISPMANX_UPDATE_HANDLE_T update = vc_dispmanx_update_start(0);

    VC_DISPMANX_ALPHA_T alpha =
    {
            DISPMANX_FLAGS_ALPHA_FIXED_ALL_PIXELS, 
            255, /*alpha 0->255*/ 0
    };

    vc_dispmanx_rect_set(&sourceRectangle, 0, 0, pAVCodecContext->width, pAVCodecContext->height);
    vc_dispmanx_rect_set(&destinationRectangle, 0, 0, pAVCodecContext->width, pAVCodecContext->height);

    DISPMANX_ELEMENT_HANDLE_T bgElement = vc_dispmanx_element_add(update, display, 1 /* layer */, &destinationRectangle, bgResource, &sourceRectangle, DISPMANX_PROTECTION_NONE, &alpha, NULL /* clamp */, DISPMANX_NO_ROTATE);
    assert(bgElement != 0);

    result = vc_dispmanx_update_submit_sync(update);
    assert(result == 0);

    int frameNumber =0;
    AVFrame *pFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    uint8_t *buffer = NULL;
    int numBytes;

    // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
    numBytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, pAVCodecContext->width, pAVCodecContext->height, 1);

    buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes * sizeof(uint8_t));
    // Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrameRGB
    av_image_fill_arrays(pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, buffer, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, pAVCodecContext->width, pAVCodecContext->height, 1);
    int pitch = ALIGN_UP(pAVCodecContext->width, 32);

    vc_dispmanx_rect_set(&destinationRectangle, 0, 0, pAVCodecContext->width,(3 * ALIGN_UP(pAVCodecContext->height, 16)) / 2);
    while (av_read_frame(pFormatContext, &avPacket) >= 0) {
            if( avPacket.stream_index == videoStreamIndex ) {
                    // For decoding, call avcodec_send_packet() to give the decoder raw compressed data in an AVPacket.
                int frameFinished = avcodec_send_packet(pAVCodecContext, &avPacket);

            while (!frameFinished) {
                // For decoding, call avcodec_receive_frame(). On success, it will return an AVFrame containing uncompressed audio or video data.
                frameFinished = avcodec_receive_frame(pAVCodecContext, pFrame);
                if (!frameFinished) {
                    vc_dispmanx_rect_set(&destinationRectangle, 0, 0, pAVCodecContext->width, (3 * ALIGN_UP(pAVCodecContext->height, 16)) / 2);
                    result = vc_dispmanx_resource_write_data(bgResource, VC_IMAGE_YUV420, ALIGN_UP(pAVCodecContext->width, 32), *pFrame->data, &destinationRectangle);
                    update = vc_dispmanx_update_start(0);
                    vc_dispmanx_element_change_source(update, bgElement, bgResource);
                    vc_dispmanx_update_submit_sync(update);
                    av_frame_unref(pFrame);
                }
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(&avPacket);
    }

    update = vc_dispmanx_update_start(0);
    vc_dispmanx_element_remove(update, bgElement);
    vc_dispmanx_update_submit_sync(update);
    vc_dispmanx_resource_delete(bgResource);
    vc_dispmanx_display_close(display);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3+, with OS Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
avcodec is libavcodec.58

I tried suggestion from following post but unfortunately without success:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=472700
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7672

Please if you have any suggestion let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the *destinationRectangle* you set just cover for Y plane, so U,V planes will not be set as yours data when you write data, that will lead to green picture. To solve it, let extend the *destinationRectangle* to size of YUV plana size (width x height x 3/2) as follow:

```
vc_dispmanx_set_rect(&destinationRextangle, 0, 0, pAVCodecContext->width, 3*pAVCodecContext->height/2);
```